# Android Permissions - Gyroscope-support with OpenGL ES2

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, gyroscope, android-market-filtering

I added a require gyroscope and OpenGL ES2 support to my Android manifest, and it seems that many more devices than should be are now eliminated on the market.

Does anyone know why the Motorola Droid4 on ICS does not support the gyroscope? The manufacturer lists that it supports it, and ICS is high enough to support gyroscope, rather than Froyo which requires interpolation via magnetic field and accelerometer

How is the gyroscope android-market-filtering done exactly?

Comment: Note that Motorola Mobility does not include a gyroscope in the DROID 4's specifications: http://www.motorola.com/us/consumers/DROID-4-by-Motorola/88569,en_US,pd.html?selectedTab=tab-2&cgid=mobile-phones#tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this line in the manifest

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" android:required="false" />
```

So your app will not be filtered, and if your app doesn't works without gyroscope you can add a notice in the description of the app.
Otherwise you say to Google that is a required function to use the app and all devices are filtered according the Google DB.

By the way, seems that the [Motorola Droid 4](http://www.motorola.com/us/consumers/DROID-4-by-Motorola/88569,en_US,pd.html?selectedTab=tab-2&cgid=mobile-phones#tab) **hasn't** any gyroscope.

> *Sensors   Proximity, ambient light, eCompass, battery temp, Accelerometer*